# Trying to iterate to avoid low performance (JAVA & JAVASCRIPT & SQL)

Tags: javascript, java, sql, loops, collections

I got this definition table. Every product has it's own **ATTRIBUTE1, ATTRIBUTE2, ATTRIBUTE3, ATTRIBUTE4, ATTRIBUTE5, ATTRIBUTE6,**  that includes them in a specific deposit

```
DEPOSIT_ID  ATTRIBUTE1  ATTRIBUTE2  ATTRIBUTE3  ATTRIBUTE4  ATTRIBUTE5  ATTRIBUTE6
41          *            006|001        *           0M          *           *
40          *            003|006      41|29      !94|46       !E5|E6        *
39          *            003|006       45          !94          *           *
38          *            003|006      10|59         *          18|P5        *
37          *              001         23          !94          *           *
36          *              001        26|SSH       !57          *           *
35          *              001        24|25      !81|57|0M      *           *
34          *              001         22          !57        !Q1|O3        *
33          *              001         21         !81|57        B7          *
32          *              001        SSJ|62      !81|57        *           9FA
```

> "*" means that it can accept any valid attribute
>
> "|" means it can be one or another (i.e: 006|001 means that it can be 006 or 001)
>
> "!" means it cannot be that value (i.e: !81|57 means that it cannot be 81 or 57)

```
Note: 
a "*" for ATTRIBUTE1 would be a value = "GH"
a "*" for ATTRIBUTE2 would be a value = "001"
a "*" for ATTRIBUTE3 would be a value = "41"
a "*" for ATTRIBUTE4 would be a value = "0M"
a "*" for ATTRIBUTE5 would be a value = "B7"
a "*" for ATTRIBUTE5 would be a value = "9FA"
```

### EVERY attribute has a set of values and the "*" means it can be any, that's why i posted some valid attributes for each ATTRIBUTE column

**For example:**

Product "a" has these attributes (also called item configuration):

```
{
attribute1: "GH"
attribute2: "001"
attribute3: "VT"
attribute4: "OM"
attribute5: "JU"
attribute6: "YU"
}
```

[image]

So, for that item configuration, product "a" belongs" to **DEPOSIT_ID: 41**

---

Suppose that i want to know which is the DEPOSIT ID for this item configuration:

```
{
attribute1: "GH"
attribute2: "001"
attribute3: "23"
attribute4: "JU"
attribute5: "KO"
attribute6: "YU"
}
```

It should give me the deposit_id = 37.

What would it be the best to solve this by using JAVA or JAVASCRIPT or SQL?

Comment: Java *AND* JavaScript or SQL Query? That doesn't make sense, I'm afraid.

Comment: Hey @HovercraftFullOfEels i'm trying to solve this using Java or Javascript or SQL

Comment: Does your database support regular expressions?

Comment: Hey @phatfingers i'm using MariaDB so i think it does support it

Comment: @phatfingers i'm looking for the best way to solve this and everything seems to have low performance

Answer (score 1):

I don't see how you can avoid a full table scan with each query, which may be what is impacting performance depending on the number of rows.  If your schema was restructured to spread multiple values into multiple rows rather than pipe-separated into the same field, you'd have a better chance at indexing fields used in your queries, which could dramatically improve performance depending on the size of your dataset.

That said, a query along the lines of the following should be sufficient:

```
SELECT * FROM product WHERE
  (attribute1='*' OR attribute1 REGEXP '\bGH\b' and not attribute1 REGEXP '!.*\bGH\b')
  AND (attribute2='*' OR attribute2 REGEXP '\b001\b' and not attribute2 REGEXP '!.*\b001\b')
  AND (attribute3='*' OR attribute3 REGEXP '\b23\b' and not attribute3 REGEXP '!.*\b23\b')
  AND (attribute4='*' OR attribute4 REGEXP '\bJU\b' and not attribute4 REGEXP '!.*\bJU\b')
  AND (attribute5='*' OR attribute5 REGEXP '\bKO\b' and not attribute5 REGEXP '!.*\bKO\b')
  AND (attribute6='*' OR attribute6 REGEXP '\bYU\b' and not attribute6 REGEXP '!.*\bYU\b');
```

Comment: Hey pal, thank you very very much for replying!. Could you please explain your query to me? What are you actually doing in there? Is it possible to try it online?

Comment: What does this line mean?: "attribute6='*' OR attribute6 REGEXP '\bYU\b' and not attribute6 REGEXP '!YU\b'". What it is doing?

Comment: It's checking to see if the value either equals '*', or contains a literal such as 'YU' (using word boundaries `\b` to ensure a complete word, avoiding, for example 'YUL' or 'XYU').  Finally, it's checking to see whether to avoid inclusion if '!YU', which I might not understand correctly, as it doesn't make much sense when paired with other values.

Comment: Is there any difference between '57' and '!81|57'?

Comment: !81|57 means that in order to belong to that deposit the value MUST NOT BE 81 or 57

Comment: Ah, ok, was thinking '!' only applied to the 81.  I'll make adjustments.

Comment: Alright, pal. The thing is that every ATTRIBUTE COLUMN has different values that makes a product fit on it. I will be "sending" different PRODUCTS CONFIGURATIONs and they must fit on a deposit, do you get me?

Comment: Pal, how would you do in JAVA to do something like this? It is even possible?

Comment: Learn how to build a parameterized query and/or use a library to connect to your database.  It's too broad a topic to address here.

Comment: Pal, suppose that i am checking if attribute2 has '003' based on what i sent. I need to validate whether it has "*" or "003" or "003|" bacause there exist a value "003|006" on the definition table. How should i handle the "1" thing?

Comment: The answer already addresses that.

Comment: If i use this it does shows me something as input: AND (business_unit='*' OR business_unit = '003|006') but if i use this it does not AND (business_unit='*' OR business_unit REGEXP '\b003|006b\')

Comment: Your post suggests that your table contains  pipe-separated criteria but only shows simple values in your item configurations.  Your last question seems to indicate pipe-separated data in both places.  If that's the case, then I misunderstood your actual requirements and my answer may be of little help.

Answer (score 1):

You can compile the criteria into Java objects.

Interface `P` is a functional interface with only `boolean test(String s)` method. The static method `P compile(String c)` of this interface converts a string `*` or `!94|46` into a `P` object.

For example if you call `P.compile("*")`, it will return like this.

```
new P() {
   @Override
   public boolean test(String s) {
       return true;
   }
}
```

If you call `P.compile("!94|46")`, it will return like this.

```
new P() {
    Set<String> SET = Set.of("94", "96");
    @Override
    public boolean test(String s) {
        return !SET.contains(s);
    }
}
```

Note that `P.compile()` creates these objects directly, rather than generating and compiling Java source code.

Record `Rule` is a collection of `P` objects associated with an `id`. It has a `boolean test(Data data)` method that takes a `Data` object and tests whether it matches its own criteria.

```
interface P {
    boolean test(String s);

    public static P compile(String c) {
        if (c.equals("*"))
            return s -> true;
        boolean not = false;
        if (c.startsWith("!")) {
            not = true;
            c = c.substring(1);
        }
        Set<String> values = Stream.of(c.split("\\|")).collect(Collectors.toSet());
        return not ? s -> !values.contains(s) : s -> values.contains(s);
    }
}

record Rule(int id, P a1, P a2, P a3, P a4, P a5, P a6) {
    public Rule(String id, String a1, String a2, String a3, String a4, String a5, String a6) {
        this(Integer.parseInt(id), P.compile(a1), P.compile(a2), P.compile(a3),
            P.compile(a4), P.compile(a5), P.compile(a6));
    }
    boolean test(Data data) {
        return a1.test(data.a1()) && a2.test(data.a2()) && a3.test(data.a3())
            && a4.test(data.a4()) && a5.test(data.a5()) && a6.test(data.a6());
    }
}

record Data(String a1, String a2, String a3, String a4, String a5, String a6) { }
```

and

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    List<Rule> rules = List.of(
        new Rule("41", "*", "006|001", "*", "OM", "*", "*"),
        new Rule("40", "*", "003|006", "41|29", "!94|46", "!E5|E6", "*"),
        new Rule("39", "*", "003|006", "45", "!94", "*", "*"),
        new Rule("38", "*", "003|006", "10|59", "*", "18|P5", "*"),
        new Rule("37", "*", "001", "23", "!94", "*", "*"),
        new Rule("36", "*", "001", "26|SSH", "!57", "*", "*"),
        new Rule("35", "*", "001", "24|25", "!81|57|0M", "*", "*"),
        new Rule("34", "*", "001", "22", "!57", "!Q1|O3", "*"),
        new Rule("33", "*", "001", "21", "!81|57", "B7", "*"),
        new Rule("32", "*", "001", "SSJ|62", "!81|57", "*", "9FA"));

    List<Data> list = List.of(
        new Data("GH", "001", "VT", "OM", "JU", "YU"),
        new Data("GH", "001", "23", "JU", "KO", "YU"));

    for (Data data : list) {
        int id = -1;
        for (Rule rule : rules)
            if (rule.test(data)) {
                id = rule.id();
                break;
            }
        System.out.println(data + " -> " + id);
    }
}
```

output:

```
Data[a1=GH, a2=001, a3=VT, a4=OM, a5=JU, a6=YU] -> 41
Data[a1=GH, a2=001, a3=23, a4=JU, a5=KO, a6=YU] -> 37
```

For Java1.8

```
import java.util.Arrays;
import java.util.List;
import java.util.Set;
import java.util.stream.Collectors;
import java.util.stream.Stream;

public class Java8 {

    public interface P {
        boolean test(String s);

        public static P compile(String c) {
            if (c.equals("*"))
                return s -> true;
            boolean not = false;
            if (c.startsWith("!")) {
                not = true;
                c = c.substring(1);
            }
            Set<String> values = Stream.of(c.split("\\|")).collect(Collectors.toSet());
            return not ? s -> !values.contains(s) : s -> values.contains(s);
        }
    }

    public static class Rule {
        private final int id;
        private final P a1, a2, a3, a4, a5, a6;
        public Rule(String id, String a1, String a2, String a3, String a4, String a5, String a6) {
            this.id = Integer.parseInt(id);
            this.a1 = P.compile(a1); this.a2 = P.compile(a2); this.a3 = P.compile(a3);
            this.a4 = P.compile(a4); this.a5 = P.compile(a5); this.a6 = P.compile(a6);
        }
        public int id() { return id; }
        boolean test(Data data) {
            return a1.test(data.a1()) && a2.test(data.a2()) && a3.test(data.a3())
                && a4.test(data.a4()) && a5.test(data.a5()) && a6.test(data.a6());
        }
    }

    public static class Data {
        final String a1, a2, a3, a4, a5, a6;
        public Data(String a1, String a2, String a3, String a4, String a5, String a6) {
            this.a1 = a1; this.a2 = a2; this.a3 = a3;
            this.a4 = a4; this.a5 = a5; this.a6 = a6;
        }
        public String a1() { return a1; } public String a2() { return a2; }
        public String a3() { return a3; } public String a4() { return a4; }
        public String a5() { return a5; } public String a6() { return a6; }
        @Override
        public String toString() {
            return String.format("Data[a1=%s, a2=%s, a3=%s, a4=%s, a5=%s, a6=%s]",
                a1, a2, a3, a4, a5, a6);
        }
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        List<Rule> rules = Arrays.asList(
            new Rule("41", "*", "006|001", "*", "OM", "*", "*"),
            new Rule("40", "*", "003|006", "41|29", "!94|46", "!E5|E6", "*"),
            new Rule("39", "*", "003|006", "45", "!94", "*", "*"),
            new Rule("38", "*", "003|006", "10|59", "*", "18|P5", "*"),
            new Rule("37", "*", "001", "23", "!94", "*", "*"),
            new Rule("36", "*", "001", "26|SSH", "!57", "*", "*"),
            new Rule("35", "*", "001", "24|25", "!81|57|0M", "*", "*"),
            new Rule("34", "*", "001", "22", "!57", "!Q1|O3", "*"),
            new Rule("33", "*", "001", "21", "!81|57", "B7", "*"),
            new Rule("32", "*", "001", "SSJ|62", "!81|57", "*", "9FA"));

        List<Data> list = Arrays.asList(
            new Data("GH", "001", "VT", "OM", "JU", "YU"),
            new Data("GH", "001", "23", "JU", "KO", "YU"));

        for (Data data : list) {
            int id = -1;
            for (Rule rule : rules)
                if (rule.test(data)) {
                    id = rule.id();
                    break;
                }
            System.out.println(data + " -> " + id);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Hey pal, thanks for replying!
Could you please explain to me your p Interface and record Rule method? what is it doing?

Comment: @programming_amazing Added a little explanation. I'm sorry that I'm not good at English.

Comment: Thanks for replying, pal. How am i supponse to try your code, pal? I copy & paste it but it throws some errors such as: 'record' is not a valid type name; it is a restricted identifier and not allowed as a type identifier in Java 1.8

Comment: @programming_amazing I'll add the code adapted for Java8. Please wait.

Comment: alright, pal. I also had this error: Constructor call must be the first statement in a constructor... Also this: Rule cannot be resolved to a type

Comment: @programming_amazing I added Java8 version.

Comment: Yeah, it worked!. Pal, what is the most efficient way to solve this? Is you r code efficient at all?

Comment: I'm not sure about that. However, solutions using SQL generally cannot avoid file I/O. This solution does no file I/O. `String.split()` and `Collectors.toSet()` are expensive in this program, but they are executed only once at `compile()` time for each condition.

Comment: Pal, could you please explain to me what you do in P compile? What it is actually doing?

Comment: I added examples of `P.compile()`.

Comment: I'm checking this out, pal